# Why there are no brackets in $e^x$ or $\ln x$?

Tags: functions, notation

I have seen that one uses often brackets when one evaluates functions, like $f(3)=5$, never $f3=5$. But why some textbooks makes it clear that it is okay to write $\ln 3$ or $e^3$ instead of $\ln (3)$ or $e^{(3)}$? Why do $\ln, e, \sin,\cos,\tan\ldots$ uses different rules of bracketing compared to $f,g,h\ldots$?

Comment: Brackets are supposed to help make expressions clearer. Some things, though, are more readable without them, and they are omitted in these cases. Note, of course, that you are likely happy with $ 5 + 3$ instead of $(5+3)$ even though $2\cdot (5 +3)$ and $2\cdot 5 + 3$ don't mean the same thing (given standard conventions).

Comment: Mathematical notation is just a convention. In many cases you can write things faster and short with no risk (or very low risk) to be confused. Conventions change all the time, slowly, but they do. From the existence of LATEX or personal computers some notations are evolving.

Comment: Although I agree one never sees $f3=5$, nonetheless one does sometimes see a similar thing with variables, namely something like $fx=y$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because $e^x, \log x, \sin x$ are all used so often that having to repeatedly use brackets would be annoying. There is also very little chance of confusion. It is basically the same reason why $\log, \sin$ etc have their own latex code...

Answer (score 1):

The power notation requires no parenthesis:

$$x^y.$$

On the opposite, function invocations do:

$$\ln(x),\sin(x),\exp(x)\cdots$$

By laziness, they are sometimes omitted

$$\ln x, \sin x,\exp x\cdots$$

It's all about making sure that the expressions can be unambiguously parsed.

Comment: There are other reasons, in addition to laziness. For example, when writing nested expressions the high proportion of parenthesis characters can make it harder to visually scan the expression. So one might prefer to write $\ln(\cos x)$ instead of $\ln(\cos(x))$.